# Hyperref command doesn't work with report document class

Tags: hyperref, incompatibility

When I use 
    \usepackage{hyperref} it doesn't complile the code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\oddsidemargin 0.0in
\textwidth 6.27in
\topmargin -0.5in
\textheight 9.69in
\footskip 0.5in
\urlstyle{sf}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{subfig}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{xxx}
dfdsfdsfd
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The incompatibility here is not with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), but instead with loading two sub-float packages: [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) and [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig). Since you're using [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) already, I'd stick with `subcaption` rather than `subfig`.

Other suggestions include:

- Use [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to set your document layout/dimensions, not [`a4wide`](http://ctan.org/pkg/a4wide);
- Don't load packages twice (like [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) and `amssymb`);
- Load *either* [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) (preferred) *or* [`enumerate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate), but not *both*.

Comment: but I have sub figures and sub captions in my latex code

Comment: @Harry: That's fine, since both provide that functionality - they're not compatible though. So you have to make a decision between using the one *or* the other. Look at the [`subfig` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf) and the [`subcaption` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) and make a decision in terms of the user interface you prefer. I'd go with the latter `subcaption`, since you're already using [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) (by the same package author).